# How to implement my product resource into a Pods structure?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Reading http://www.ember-cli.com/#pod-structure

Lets say I have a product resource. Which currently has the following directory structure:

```
app/controllers/products/base.js
app/controllers/products/edit.js
app/controllers/products/new.js
app/controllers/products/index.js
```

With pods all the logic in these files are put in a single file `app/products/controller.js`?

At the same time, my `routes` and `templates` for these resources currently look like:

```
app/routes/products/base.js
app/routes/products/edit.js
app/routes/products/new.js
app/routes/products/index.js
app/templates/products/-form.hbs
app/templates/products/edit.hbs
app/templates/products/index.hbs
app/templates/products/new.hbs
app/templates/products/show.hbs
```

How should this be converted to Pods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ember generate --pod --dry-run` to help with that:

```
$ ember g -p -d route products/base
version: 0.1.6
The option '--dryRun' is not supported by the generate command. Run `ember generate --help` for a list of supported options.
installing
You specified the dry-run flag, so no changes will be written.
  create app/products/base/route.js
  create app/products/base/template.hbs
installing
You specified the dry-run flag, so no changes will be written.
  create tests/unit/products/base/route-test.js
$
```

(I don't know why it complains yet it honours the option, might be a bug).

So you'd end up with a structure like:

```
app/controllers/products/base/route.js
app/controllers/products/edit/route.js
```

etc.